# Couldn't dismiss mr. robot

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Today I was greeted with MR. ROBOT, I wanted to close the prompt but the little x didn't work.

Clicking above the prompt, to the right of the code, did close the prompt however.

[image: Human verification popup.]

Answer (score 3):

I am unable to duplicate this. Given its age, I assume it was fixed in one of our Stacks updates over the last three years. Marking this as completed.